Spring Security authentication lost between requests after upgrade to spring-security6
Been struggling quite a lot with this.
Doing form-based login which succeeds (recieves a http200 with a jsessionid response cookie):
 public SecurityFilterChain formLoginSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, RestAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint, RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler, RestAuthenticationLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler, SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED))
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/"), antMatcher("/index.html")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/assets/**")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/system-info/**"),antMatcher("/api/system-messages/public")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/admin/system-messages/**")).hasAuthority(Privileges.IDM_ICDP_SYSTEM_ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/admin/applied-scripts")).hasAuthority(Privileges.IDM_ICDP_SYSTEM_ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/admin/**")).hasAuthority(Privileges.IDM_ICDP_ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/viewer/**")).hasAnyAuthority(Privileges.IDM_ICDP_ADMIN, Privileges.IDM_ICDP_VIEWER)
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/case-decision/search")).hasAnyAuthority(Privileges.IDM_ICDP_ADMIN, Privileges.IDM_ICDP_VIEWER)
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/**")).authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                        .successHandler(successHandler)
                        .failureHandler(failureHandler)
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                );
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }
    // @formatter:off

This is my SuccessHandler (nothing special happening here)
public class RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private final int sessionTimeout;


    public RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler(int sessionTimeout) {
        this.sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeout);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

}

When issuing the next request to get user details on a secured endpoint the session is totally lost and no Authentication is found, which is cleary indicated in the provided logs.
According to the logs the SecurityContext with the authentication is stored without problems in the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository by the filterChain after the successful login. As I understand it, the upgrade to spring-security6 there are some changes if you use BasicAuth where you have to do this saving yourself from now on, but since this is formLogin that should not be neccesary (as also indicated by the logs).
I have a spring-boot test where this is reproduced and when debugging the first filter in the DefaultSecurityFilterChain (DisableEncodeUrlFilter) the session is gone.
This is the logs:
15:15:02.742 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@429fde8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@393dc0fa, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3473addb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@910b21b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7179f9bd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@427aaa0d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3ff3601e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@490b430a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@232a506a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@40984b9b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6eb0c6de, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@22915d1a]] (1/1)
15:15:02.742 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /api/login
15:15:02.744 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
15:15:02.747 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
15:15:02.749 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
15:15:02.751 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
15:15:02.752 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
15:15:02.752 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/api/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/api/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/api/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/api/logout', DELETE]]
15:15:02.752 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
15:15:02.755 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authenticating request with $Proxy114 (1/1)
15:15:02.759 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE o.s.s.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy - Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
15:15:02.767 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=admin, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[access-rest-api, access-icdp-admin]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@20222019]
15:15:02.768 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=admin, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[access-rest-api, access-icdp-admin]]
15:15:02.769 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
15:15:02.831 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@429fde8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@393dc0fa, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3473addb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@910b21b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7179f9bd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@427aaa0d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3ff3601e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@490b430a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@232a506a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@40984b9b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6eb0c6de, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@22915d1a]] (1/1)
15:15:02.831 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /api/account
15:15:02.831 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
15:15:02.831 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
15:15:02.831 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/api/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/api/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/api/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/api/logout', DELETE]]
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE o.s.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/api/login', POST]
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
15:15:02.832 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
15:15:02.834 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
15:15:02.834 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
15:15:02.835 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE o.s.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
15:15:02.835 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE o.springframework.security.web.context.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
15:15:02.835 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE o.springframework.security.web.context.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
15:15:02.835 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE o.s.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
15:15:02.835 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
15:15:02.836 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
15:15:02.837 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE o.s.s.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@7159b841]
15:15:02.838 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE o.s.s.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@7159b841] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@4be6840e
15:15:02.840 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98)

This is my spring-boot-test:
    @Test
    void testLoginAndGetAccount() {
        // Mock the authenticateUser method
        HelixUser mockUser = new HelixUser();
        mockUser.setId("admin");
        mockUser.setFirstName("Admin");
        mockUser.setLastName("User");
        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>(List.of(Privileges.ACCESS_REST_API, Privileges.IDM_ICDP_ADMIN));
        mockUser.setPrivileges(privileges);
        List<HelixGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        // Configure the mock to return the mockUser when authenticateUser is called
        when(remoteIdmService.authenticateUser("admin", "admin")).thenReturn(mockUser);

        User mockFlowableUser = Mockito.mock(User.class);

        when(userService.getUser("admin")).thenReturn(mockFlowableUser);


        // Form data
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("username", "admin");
        map.add("password", "admin");

        // Headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        // Request entity
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        // Construct URL
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/icdp/api/login";

        // Make the POST request
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);

        // Assertions
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()).isTrue();
        
        // Assuming the login was successful, now attempt to access /icdp/api/account
        String accountUrl = "http://localhost:" + port + "/icdp/api/account";
        ResponseEntity<String> accountResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(accountUrl, String.class);

        // Assertions on the account response, FAILS because there is no HttpSession
        assertThat(accountResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()).isTrue();
    }

What am I missing here? How can the session disappear?

i dont really understand why you think restTemplate would keep state of your cookies. You are basically doing one request to login. Then you are making a completely separate to access account information. You seem to think that restTemplate magically includes the cookie from the previous request. RestTemplate is not a browser. Also RestTemplate is deprecated, you should be using WebClient instead, and you should be using the test tools that spring provides

Well, the reason for that is that the exact same integration test works before the upgrade of spring-boot and spring-security which makes me think the cookie are included in the subsequent requests using the same instance of the TestRestTemplate (which does not seem to be deprecated in spring-boot 3.1.6 which I'm on). I am also getting the exact same behaviour when running in a browser. BTW In my @BeforeEach I am instantiating the TestRestTemplate with new TestRestTemplate(TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES). With out that option the test fails on the not-upgraded stack.

UPDATE: So this made me look into the implementation used by the TestRestTemplate and it revealed that the upgraded branch did not use the apache.httpcommons implementation which the master branch did. Adding the org.apache.httpcomponents.client5 to the classpath made the test pass for the upgrade. Thanks for steering me in that direction.

Well the correct technical term is that resttemplate is in maintnance mode meaning that it will not get updated.
